# Cannot get the tab containing empty required field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Within a modal there are tabs containing required fields :

```
<div class="col-md-12 scrollable_h" style="max-width: 100%;" id="block_clients">
    
    <table id="liste_clients" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Compte</th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Pr&eacute;nom</th>
                <th>Adresse</th>
                <th>Ville(Code)</th>
                <th>T&eacute;l&eacute;phone / mobile</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Nationalit&eacute;</th>
                <th>Qualit&eacute;</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Segment</th>
                <th>Prescripteur</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    
    <div id="modalAjoutClient" class="modal">
        <form id="frmClient">
            <input type="hidden" id="mode_" name="mode_" />
            <div class="modal-content tabs">
                <div class="modal-header" style="padding:0px;font-size: 13px !important;justify-content: center !important;">
                    <span class="close"></span>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="font-family: 'Public sans';">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkupClient" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkupClient" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkupClient">
                                <div class="navbar-nav tab-registers">
                                    <a class="nav-link active-tab" aria-current="page" href="#block_add_client_adr_comm">Adresse Commerciale</a>&emsp;&emsp;
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#block_add_client_adr_factur">Adresse Facturation</a>&emsp;&emsp;
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#block_add_client_facturation">Facturation</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row tab-bodies">
                        <div class="col-md-12 scrollable_h" style="display:block; max-width: 100%;" id="block_add_client_adr_comm">
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Nom :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="nom" maxlength="100" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="telephone" maxlength="45">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Pr&eacute;nom :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="prenom" maxlength="100">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Mobile :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="mobile" maxlength="20">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Ville :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="ville" maxlength="45">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Nationalit&eacute; :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <select class="form-select champ-modal listbox-modal medium" name="nationalite" required>
                                                <option value=''></option>
                                                <option value='A'>Autriche</option>
                                                <option value='AF'>Afghanistan</option>
                                                <option value='AL'>Albania</option>
                                                ...
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Code Postal :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="codePostal" maxlength="45">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Qualit&eacute; :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <select class="form-select champ-modal listbox-modal medium" name="qualite">
                                                <option value="SOC">Soci&eacute;t&eacute;</option>
                                                <option value="MR">Monsieur</option>
                                                <option value="MME">Madame</option>
                                                <option value="MLLE">Mademoiselle</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 scrollable_h" style="display:none; max-width: 100%;" id="block_add_client_adr_factur">
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Nom :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="nomFacturation" maxlength="45" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="telephoneFacturation" maxlength="15">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Pr&eacute;nom :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="prenomFacturation" maxlength="45">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Mobile :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="mobileFacturation" maxlength="15">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Adresse :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="adresseFacturation" maxlength="100">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">E-mail :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="emailFacturation" maxlength="80">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Ville :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="villeFacturation" maxlength="45">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Nationalit&eacute; :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <select class="form-select champ-modal listbox-modal medium" name="paysFacturation" required>
                                                <option value=''></option>
                                                <option value='A'>Autriche</option>
                                                <option value='AF'>Afghanistan</option>
                                                <option value='AL'>Albania</option>
                                                ...
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 scrollable_h" style="display:none; max-width: 100%;" id="block_add_client_facturation">
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Compte de prise en charge :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="" maxlength="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Compte de tarification :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="" maxlength="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row block-champs">
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Compte d'allotement :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="" maxlength="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-7" style="padding-left: 45px;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="label">Compte de fid&eacute;lit&eacute; :</label>
                                        <div class="" style="position: relative;">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm champ-modal" name="" maxlength="">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                              
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" style="background-color: black; color: white; font-size: 12px;" id="btnValiderPopupAjoutClient">Valider</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn dark btn-outline dismiss-modal" style="background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 700; border: 1px solid black;">Annuler</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript code for the tab mechanism :

```
tabs = [];
divs = [];
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#frmClient .tabs')).forEach((tab_container, TabID) => {
    const registers = tab_container.querySelector('.tab-registers');
    const bodies = tab_container.querySelector('.tab-bodies');
    Array.from(registers.children).forEach((el, i) => {
        el.setAttribute('aria-controls', `${TabID}_${i}`);
        bodies.children[i]?.setAttribute('id', `${TabID}_${i}`);
        el.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
            let activeRegister = registers.querySelector('.active-tab');
            activeRegister.classList.remove('active-tab');
            activeRegister = el;
            activeRegister.classList.add('active-tab');
            let tabnum = `${i}`;
            changeBody_(registers, bodies, activeRegister, tabnum);
        });
        tabs.push(el);
        divs.push(el.getAttribute("href"));
    });
});

function changeBody_(registers, bodies, activeRegister, tabnum) {
    Array.from(registers.children).forEach((el, i) => {
        if (bodies.children[i]) {
            bodies.children[i].style.display = el == activeRegister ? 'block' : 'none';
        }
        el.setAttribute('aria-expanded', el == activeRegister ? 'true' : 'false');
    })
}
```

At runtime there is the error `invalid form control with name='nomFacturation' is not focusable` and `invalid form control with name='paysFacturation' is not focusable` when clicking the submit button in the modal. So here is how I manage it :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnValiderPopupAjoutClient").on("click", function(e) {
        $("#frmClient").attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
        let videExist = false;
        let onglet = 0;
        for(let i in divs) {
            let obligatoiresVide = $(divs[i]+" input,textarea,select").filter('[required]').filter(function(idx) {
                return $(this).val() == "";
            });
            console.log("============ number of empty required =",obligatoiresVide.length);
            if (obligatoiresVide.length > 0) {
                videExist = true;
                onglet = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videExist) {
            console.log("=========== tab index =",onglet);
            tabs[onglet].click();
            $("#frmClient").removeAttr('novalidate');
        }
    });

    ....

});
```

But at runtime when I fill in all the required fields on the first tab and leave the other tab's required fields blank then the console showed `============ number of empty required = 1` and `=========== tab index = 0`, although it should be `=========== tab index = 1` ! So what is wrong in my codes ?

Comment: You build the wrong selector. `divs[i]+" input,textarea,select"` will result in `#foo input,textarea,select` - and that selects `input` elements that are descendants of `#foo` - and `textarea` and `select` elements _across the whole document_.

Comment: I´m not sure if you can solve that like this. what if you have empty required fields in both tabs? What comes to my mind is that you can only switch to next tab when all required fields in current tab are filled out ;-)

Comment: @johnSmith I filled all required fields on the first tab

Comment: @CBroe so how to select all input and select elements descendants of #foo ?

Comment: `#foo input, #foo textarea, #foo select`. Or use `$(divs[i]).find("input,textarea,select")` - select the ancestor first, and then find the desired elements in there; that way you don't have to dynamically insert `divs[i]` in _multiple_ places into your selector string.

Comment: Another work around could be to use the localstorage no ?
that way you could check if values are over there.
You could also create an object whith the values with something like :

let requiredValues{
value1 : document.getElementById('el1') ? document.getElementById('el1') : null,
ect
}

and on each listener update those values (or create a function to fetch them in localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

Is I understand it you need a form where you can navigate between tabs. I started all over -- so, this is just a suggestion for the structure.

The main thing is the event listener for `invalid` on the form. I use `preventDefault()` and the useCapture parameter to stop the default behavior of an invalid form field. Instead I set the class name to `invalid` on the form field and set the fieldset name into the data-feedback attribute of the form. This can be use for styling the tabs.

Now, you can navigate between tabs and see what tabs/fieldsets are invalid.

```js
// navigating the tabs
document.forms.form01.querySelector('.tabs').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'A') {
    let tabs = e.target.closest('ul.tabs');
    tabs.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => li.classList.remove('current'));
    e.target.closest('li').classList.add('current');
    e.target.closest('form').querySelectorAll('fieldset').forEach(fieldset => fieldset.classList.remove('current'));
    e.target.closest('form')[e.target.getAttribute('href')].classList.add('current');
  }
});

// when the form is valid it will submit
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submitting...');
});

// when a form field is not valid
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
  let feedback = new Set(e.target.form.dataset.feedback.split(' '));
  feedback.delete(''); // in the case of an empty item
  feedback.add(e.target.closest('fieldset').name);
  e.target.form.dataset.feedback = [...feedback.values()].join(' ');
}, true);

// when there is input on a form field
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let fieldset = e.target.closest('fieldset');
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
    if (fieldset.validity.valid) {
      let feedback = new Set(e.target.form.dataset.feedback.split(' '));
      feedback.delete(fieldset.name);
      e.target.form.dataset.feedback = [...feedback.values()].join(' ');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input.invalid {
  border: red solid;
}

fieldset {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

fieldset.current {
  display: flex;
}

form[data-feedback~="fieldset1"] li.fieldset1 {
  background-color: orange;
}

form[data-feedback~="fieldset2"] li.fieldset2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.tabs li.current a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01" data-feedback="">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="fieldset1 current"><a href="fieldset1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="fieldset2"><a href="fieldset2">Test 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <fieldset name="fieldset1" class="current">
    <label>Text 1<input type="text" name="text1" required></label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="fieldset2">
     <label>Text 2<input type="text" name="text2" required></label>
  </fieldset>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```